# mongodb use $regex with array of strings

Tags: mongodb

I know this isn't possible. But is there another way to get something similar that is also efficient? Or should I just skip this idea?

What I am looking for is something similar to:

```
collection.find({username:{$regex: {$in: ["user", "use"]}}})
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually want to find something like:

```
collection.find({username:{$in: [/user/, /use/]}});
```